# Why is Spring Security HTTP BASIC redirecting to wrong URL?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a simple Spring Security (3.x) configuration to require HTTP BASIC auth for a subset of resources in my application.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="https" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

App is deployed at context root `ctx`. I'm mapping patterns `/secured/*` onto the Spring Security filter chain.

Requests to resources `https://server:httpsport/ctx/secured/blah` work fine. So does a request to `https://server:httpsport/ctx/secured`. However, when I switch to unsecured, eg. `http://host:port/ctx/secured` it seems like the redirect is coming back wrong, duplicating the context root. In my logs I can see that a request to `/ctx/ctx/secured/...` is made.

Can someone suggest what the problem is or where I should look?

Comment: Have you intercepted the 302 with fiddler or some kind of HTTP proxy or HTTP capture to ensure the 302 actually has the /ctx/ctx?  The redirect URL (the part past the port number) generated by Spring should be `request.getRequestURI() + ((queryString == null) ? "" : ("?" + queryString));`

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have encountered the same duplicate context path problem. It works when I develop locally. But it is a problem when proxing behind nginx in production.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found answer here : http://myshittycode.com/2014/06/12/spring-security-forcing-urls-to-use-https/

So in my case problem was with using not default HTTP and HTTPS ports.
In such case adding port mapping can help.

```
    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="{yourHttpPort}" https="{yourHttpsPort}" />
    </port-mappings>
```